# perl create character by code point example from the camel book

Tags: perl, utf-8

I have a fairly basic question.

I am going through the camel book 6th edition. In chapter 2 scalar data one example code is this:

```
$alef = chr (0x05d0);
```

I tried to print that with the following but it printed blank lines.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use utf8;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
#use open qw/:std :utf8/;

$alef = chr(0x05D0);
print $alef;

$alpha = chr(hex('03B1'));
print $alpha;

$omega = chr(0x03C9);
print $omega;
```

Then I checked the documentation for the UTF-8 and while there isn't a 05D0, there is a 005D, which would give me a right square bracket ']'.

My question is this: was there something that I missed leading to the blank lines or was it just a type on the publisher/author's part?

and the alpha and omega works find if it weren't for alef. :)

Thanks
Davy

Comment: I get a Hebrew alef (א), an alpha (α) and an omega (ω) printed when I run this code (on Linux and OS X). However, it does work better if you put a `\n` after each print statement.  Perhaps it is something to do with your platform.

Comment: I am running cygwin on windows 7, maybe you are right

Comment: Perl on the windows console is known to be pretty buggy when it comes to Unicode stuff (unfortunately it's very hard to get right). 05D0 for Alef is correct. You should probably do any unicode-related exercises by writing to a file instead of the console.

Comment: Where did you check anyway?  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/05D0/index.htm is a good reference; I recommend bookmarking or memorizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with *UTF-8*. These are *Unicode* characters.

[U+05D0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5d0/index.htm): א

[U+03B1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b1/index.htm): α

[U+03C9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c9/index.htm): ω

If you got blank lines, your fonts might not have a glyph for those characters.

Comment: according to the book if I want to use unicode and I have to include the utf-8 pragma, and the output has to be specified as utf-8 as well.

Comment: Also, I think hobbs might have a point, I just tried the same code on my work machine and alef is printed as an x. So it might just be that this particular cygwin doesn't know alef.

Comment: @D.Zou, `use utf8;` tells Perl the source code is encoded using UTF-8. Since it only contains ASCII characters, `use utf8;` does absolutely nothing in that program.